# MySQL Error 1054: Unknown column 'nan' when updating table with None values in AWS Lambda function

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am working on a MySQL table update through an AWS Lambda function. In my code, I retrieve the data and then proceed to update my table with it. The data I'm working with contains None values. Strangely, when I run the code locally and mock the environment using "amplify mock function 'function name'", everything works as intended. However, after pushing the code to amplify and running the function in the AWS Lambda console, I encounter the following error: `MySQL Error: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'nan' in 'field list'`

The error seems to be related to the line of code where I replace 0 with None in a Pandas DataFrame: `df = df.replace(0, None)`
I have also attempted an alternative approach using the where() function: `df = df.where(pd.notnull(df), None)`

I made sure to mock my function in the environment with the same version of Pandas that I am using in the Lambda Layer. Despite this, the issue persists.

Can anyone shed some light on what might be causing this problem or suggest alternative ideas for resolving it? I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions.

Comment: The error implies that the column header is `NaN`.  Is it possible you have some unnamed columns in your dataframe?  The pandas mysql adapter can't handle that.

Comment: I double checked and no NaN columns exist.